# I want to find the polygon of n overlapping rectangles

Tags: geometry, polygons

Having n Rectangles (x1,y1,x2,y2) in each group, I need to find the polygon that contains all of them for each group.

Also, I need to detect if a group of rectangles has one or more rectangles that do not touch any other rectangle.

group 1

```
103 59  321 162
241 178 308 183
259 103 523 359
281 169 577 198
```

group 2

```
98  7   386 129
143 281 399 406
196 97  392 355
254 181 519 382
```

I don't know the best approach to solve it programmatically. I fell comfortable using C#.

The number of groups does not matter, because the solution to solve one group will be applied n times.

Comment: For the first question, find the convex hull of all the vertices (a search will point you to well known algorithms).

Comment: In case you're interested in CCG (and not just getting rid of programming challenges), there are some [good books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_in_computational_geometry#General-purpose_textbooks). The 1st one (pretty old) covers a lot of "rectangular" problems, and the 3rd one is a good contemporary "starter kit" (IMO).